# Why is my MySQL update statement, involving 2 tables not working?

Tags: mysql, sql

my update statement which i was sure would work, is this:

```
UPDATE products SET manufacturers_id = 37 where products_id = 
(select products_id from     products_to_categories where categories_id = 35);
```

but in PHPMyAdmin, the error i'm getting is this:

```
#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

but i want more than 1 row updated. i was trying to update 100 or more in a single statement. how can this be re-written so it will work? Do i have to use a join?

Comment: Have you tried changing `products_id =` to `products_id in` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use IN instead of =

```
UPDATE
  products
SET
  manufacturers_id = 37
WHERE
  products_id IN (SELECT products_id
                  FROM products_to_categories 
                  WHERE categories_id = 35);
```

or you could use a JOIN

```
UPDATE
  products INNER JOIN products_to_categories 
  ON products.product_d = products_to_categories.products_id
SET
  products.manufacturers_id = 37
WHERE
  products_to_categories.categories_id = 35
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
 UPDATE products SET manufacturers_id = 37 where products_id in 
 (select products_id from     products_to_categories where categories_id = 35);
```

change `=` to `IN`